# Proving an analytic function is rational

Tags: complex-analysis

If f is analytic in $|z| \leq1 $ and satisfies $ |f(z)| = 1$ on $|z| = 1$ prove that f is a rational function. I need a clue how to think about this? should i use the fact that f can be written as a power series?

Comment: You can see this, it is a more general case : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783741/meromorphic-on-unit-disc-with-absolute-value-1-on-the-circle-is-a-rational-funct